# Python - Getting Filename from Long Path

Tags: python, path

I have long paths to files like:

```
D:%5CMedia%5CMusic%20Videos%5CAlexis%20Jordan%20-%20Good%20Girl%2Emkv
```

What is the best way to get just the file name from there, so I end up with:

```
Alexis Jordan - Good Girl
```

From there I want to cut the Artist and Title into separate parts, but I can manage that :)

Comment: Do you have some set of keywords with you like 'Media', 'Music', 'Videos', which will remain the same?

Comment: @Vikram - Unfortunately not.  I was thinking about cutting it off from the last \ and then cutting the last 4 characters, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Also I need to convert the %20 to spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to decode the URL encoding with [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) then use the [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to split out the filename and extension:

```
import os
import urllib

path = urllib.unquote(path)
filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
```

where [`os.path.basename()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) removes the directory path, and [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) gives you a filename and extension tuple.

This then gives you the filename:

```
>>> import os
>>> import urllib
>>> path = 'D:%5CMedia%5CMusic%20Videos%5CAlexis%20Jordan%20-%20Good%20Girl%2Emkv'
>>> path = urllib.unquote(path)
>>> path
'D:\\Media\\Music Videos\\Alexis Jordan - Good Girl.mkv'
>>> filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
>>> filename
'Alexis Jordan - Good Girl'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from urllib2 import unquote
from os.path import basename

p = 'D:%5CMedia%5CMusic%20Videos%5CAlexis%20Jordan%20-%20Good%20Girl%2Emkv'
fname = basename(unquote(p))
```